# get a dict out of an ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

How can I recover a `dict` which was cast into a `numpy` `ndarray`?

I.e. for the following example, I want to recover `test_dict` from `test_array`:

```
>>> test_dict = { 'one' : 1 }
>>> test_array = np.asarray(test_dict)
>>> print repr(test_array)

array({'one': 1}, dtype=object)
```

These don't work:

```
>>> test[0]
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed

>>> dict(test)
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

>>> test.astype(dict)
array({'one': 1}, dtype=object)      # still in array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Don't move your arm like that."

But anyway, I might use:

```
>>> test_array
array({'one': 1}, dtype=object)
>>> test_array.item()
{'one': 1}
```

or for that matter

```
>>> test_array.min()
{'one': 1}
>>> test_array.max()
{'one': 1}
>>> test_array.take(0)
{'one': 1}
>>> test_array.flat[0]
{'one': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Regarding my arm pain, recovering a nested dictionary from an `npz` file yields a `dict` in an array --- like this.